# Pandas style object members

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to figure out how Pandas manages to create new object members on the fly. For example, if you do this:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

You can immediately do this:

```
df.col1
```

and get the contents of `col1`. How does Pandas create the `col1` member on the fly?

Thanks.

Comment: what about to check the repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And, of course, after asking the question, i find the answer myself.

It turns out you can use `__getattr__` to achieve this. Easiest way (and the one i happen to want) is by using a dictionary, then using `__getattr__` to return values from the dictionary, like so:

```
class test():
    def __init__(self):
        # super().__init__()
        self.adict = {'spam' : 'eggs'}

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self.adict[attr]

nt = test()
print(nt.spam)
```

`__getattr__` is called when a class attribute isn't found, as is the case here. The interpreter can't find the `spam` attribute, so it defers this to `__getattr__`. Things to keep in mind:

- If the key doesn't exist in the dictionary, this will raise a key error, not an attribute error.
- Don't use `__getattribute__`, because it is called every time an attribute is called, messing up your entire class.

Thanks to everyone for the input on this.

Answer (score 0):

[Relevant code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L327) in the repository that checks for a dictionary input:

```
class DataFrame(NDFrame):
    def __init__(self, data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None,
                 copy=False):
        if data is None:
            data = {}

        # Some other if-statements that check data types...

        elif isinstance(data, dict): mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
```

Which uses[_init_dict method](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L406):

```
def _init_dict(self, data, index, columns, dtype=None):

    if columns is not None:
       # Does some stuff - but this isn't your case

    else:
        keys = list(data.keys())
        if not isinstance(data, OrderedDict):
            # So this part is trying to sort keys to cols in alphabetical order
            # The _try_sort function is simple, exists in pandas.core.common
            keys = _try_sort(keys)
        columns = data_names = Index(keys)
```

So the real work comes from the [Index class](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexes/base.py#L106) in pandas.core.indexes.base. From there things start to get really complicated (and my understanding of what it means to explain the "how" of anything without continuing to regress until you get to machine code, started to melt away) but it's safe to say that if you give the `pandas.Index` class a 1-dimentional array of data it will create an object with a sliceable set and an associated data type.

Which is exactly what you're observing - you essentially fed it a bunch of keys and `pandas` understood that it needed to give you something back that you could access as an index (since `df.col1` is just syntactic sugar for `df['col1']`), that you could slice (`df[0:1]`), and that knew its own data types.

Comment: As i feared, the answer isn't a simple Python mechanic. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: You're welcome :) However, next time make sure to include *why* you want to know something, if it's relevant. It's very different to be curious about the internal mechanics of a package vs wanting to know how you would implement the same behavior. I believe a comment early on mentioned guessing pandas might use `__getattr__` but they deleted it after I posted my answer showing it doesn't.